# Comparison of signed int and unsigned short in c++

Tags: c++, unsigned, signed

I know that when we compare signed with unsigned the compiler converts our signed values to unsigned and when we compare a short with int the compiler converts the smaller type to the larger one. But I wrote this code to check if we compared an signed int x=0xdeadbeef and unsigned short y=0xffff then after converting the unsigned short to int we should have 0x0000ffff in y at the comparison which should be smaller than the unsigned value of x. But my code does not go into the if condition that x is larger than y. Could someone explain to me why?

CODE SNIPPET:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){

        unsigned int x=0xDEADBEEF;
        unsigned short y= 0xFFFF;

        if((signed)x > y)
                cout<<"X is larger"<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When run the code does not print that "X is larger".

Comment: Because (signed)x is negative.

Comment: but when comparing unsigned to a signed shouldn't the compiler convert it back to unsigned?

Comment: btw your code is in **C++**

Comment: because `0xDEADBEEF` cannot be represented in a 32-bit int, the result is implementation-defined - in this case negative. It is smaller than *any* unsigned short value - the unsigned short is promoted to `int` before the comparison.

Comment: I didnt understand why cant 0xdeadbeef be represented in 32 bit unsigned int. And how can it be negative while being unsigned?

Comment: @Ammar - `0xDEADBEEF` *can* be represented as an unsigned 32-bit int. It has the value 3 735 928 559. However a signed 32-bit int has a maximum value of 2 147 483 647. So what happens when you do `(signed)x` and the value is more than a billion too large?

Comment: I get that @BoPersson. So if we typecast and compare then we can force the compiler to compare a signed to an unsigned integer? Am i getting right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type-cast `x` from unsigned to signed, it results in integer overflow. Note that `signed int` can hold a smaller positive value than an `unsigned int` would. So when an integer overflow happens, on most platforms, it starts acting like your car's odometer. i.e. once the int value exceeds the max it can store, it starts from the beginning. The 'beginning' in case of signed int on 32 bit system (int32) will be `-2,147,483,648`.

So in your case x is 0xDEADBEEF or 3,735,928,559. An unsigned int on 32 bit system can store this value. However, when it is type cast to `signed`, it results in an overflow and hence the above mentioned rule applies and converts that value to -1,588,444,912. Since it is negative, your condition in the `if` statement doesn't satisfy and hence your statement never gets printed.